# How to disable subclassing for a specific abstract base class using Fluent NHibernate auto mapping

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an abstract base class that I'm referencing from one of my entities. This caused the following exception when generating the schema:

> An association from the table Audits refers to an unmapped class: Entity

Therefore, I had to include that base class in the auto persistence model:

```
autoPersistenceModel.IncludeBase<Entity>()
```

Now, my current problem is that Fluent NHibernate creates a huge mapping for the base class, providing a `joined-subclass` for each entity. This is of course not what I want.

So, the question is: how do I setup the auto mapping override of  in such a way that it doesn't perform any subclassing?

The `AutoMapping<Entity>` type only seems to provide means of choosing a subclassing strategy but no way of disabling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After giving this some thought, I realized that I could define a custom mapping, as simple as this:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id(n => n.Id);
    }
}
```